# Find the distribution of $Y_3=(Y_2|Y_1=3)$ and calculate $\mathbb E(Y_3)$

Tags: probability-distributions, sampling, descriptive-statistics

> **Question**: A random sample of size two is taken from the following distribution:
>   \begin{array}{|r|r|r|r|}
>  \hline
>          X &   0 &  1 &   2 &  3\\ \hline
>          \mathbb P(X=x) &0.3 &0.4&0.2&0.1\\ \hline
> \end{array}
>   
>   $(a)$ Find the distribution of $Y_1=X_1+X_2$ 
>   $(b)$ Find the distribution of $Y_2=X_1^2+X_2^2$ 
>   $(c)$ Find the distribution of $Y_3=(Y_2|Y_1=3)$ and calculate $\mathbb E(Y_3)$

**My approach**:
I am confused how to solve $(c)$. To make it easier I give what have I done . 
$(a)$: the distribution of $Y_1=X_1+X_2$ 
\begin{array}{|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
 \hline
         Y_1 &   0 &  1 &   2 &  3& 4 &   5 & 6\\ \hline
         \mathbb P(Y_2=y) &0.09&0.24&0.28&0.22&0.12&0.04&0.01\\ \hline
\end{array}
$(b)$: the distribution of $Y_2=X_1^2+X_2^2$ 
\begin{array}{|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
 \hline
         Y_2 &   0 &  1 &   2 &   4 &   5 &   8 &    9 & 10 & 13 & 18 \\ \hline
         \mathbb P(Y_2=y) &   0.09 &  0.24 &   0.16 &   0.12 &   0.16 &   0.04 &0.06 &0.08&0.04&0.01 \\ \hline
\end{array}
Any hint or solution will be appreciated .
Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that all involved random variables are discrete. Unfortunately, $Y_2$ and $Y_1$ are not independent, so we have to do some small calculations:

We have for all $y$ in the image of $Y_3$:
$$\Bbb P(Y_3=y):=\frac{\Bbb P(Y_2=y \cap Y_1 = 3)}{\Bbb P(Y_1=3)}\approx4.55\cdot \Bbb P(Y_2=y \cap Y_1=3).$$

Note that $Y_1=3\iff X_1+X_2=3$ which is the case in exactly the following cases:

- $X_1=0,X_2=3$ (hence, $Y_2=9$),
- $X_1=1,X_2=2$ (hence, $Y_2=5$),
- $X_1=2,X_2=1$ (hence, $Y_2=5$),
- $X_1=3,X_2=0$ (hence, $Y_2=9$).

So $Y_3$ only takes the values $5, 9$. We have 
\begin{split}\Bbb P(Y_3=5)&\approx 4.55\cdot\big(\Bbb P(X_1=1\cap X_2=2)+\Bbb P(X_1=2\cap X_2=1)\big)\\&=9.1\cdot\Bbb P(X_1=1)\cdot\Bbb P (X_2=2)=9.1\cdot0.4\cdot0.2\\&=0.728.\end{split}

And, similarly,
\begin{split}
\Bbb P(Y_3=9)&\approx 9.1\cdot\Bbb P(X_1=0)\cdot\Bbb P (X_2=3) = 9.1\cdot0.3\cdot 0.1=0.273.
\end{split}

From this, one can easily calculate $\Bbb E Y_3$.

(I am glad that my calculations got verified in the sense that $\Bbb P(Y_3=5)+\Bbb P(Y_3=9)\approx 1$.)

Comment: Thanks for a nice explanation. I will accept your answer after 23 hours according to community rule :) Thanks again

Comment: @emonhossain You‘re welcome! Feel free to upvote my answer in case you liked it.

Comment: I forgot to accept your answer :) sorry for late @Maximilian Janisch

Comment: @emonhossain No problem :D